# How to show the UISegmentController in IOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

Where you see the Blue color on image.

In iOS6 there is segment controller But when i run that code on the IOS 7 then it looks like this can anyone help me out in this. and also me getting problem with navigation controller that you also see in the image.

[image]

Comment: Thats everyone's problem!!!